# Area density under 2D homography mapping

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, linear-transformations

Given some `3x3` homography matrix `H`  (`H(3,3)=1`), mapping from 2D to 2D using homogenous coordinates (projective spaces).

How we can describe the area density of transformed planar object as function of x,y?

(for example a book cover in one image is related to the same book cover in second image by known homography, but we have different magnification in different location)

(i.e what is the correct way to apply jacobian on homogenous space)

Comment: “Area” isn’t meaningful in projective geometry.

Comment: I need to change the question. I mean to planar object homography (from one image to second image).

Comment: Write it as a linear fractional transformation.